# Data in existing ckeditor rows is reset when a new row is added using datatable

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, datatables

I have a problem with using ckeditor and datatable together in jquery.

History of this issue -

I display table using datatable which has two text column, a date column and a textarea which is converted to ckeditor instance. When I load this table from the db, the data is good and working as expected. But when I add a row to this datatable, the existing text or data in the textarea which is a ckeditor instance is reset. Through my analysis, I found that when I add a row, the fnAddRow() in datatable, redraws the table, unless its disabled. I have no problem with having the table to redraw itself, but whats paining is why the text in the ckeditor alone is reset.

Below is the snippet -

Datatable definition -

```
    var config = {

             "bJQueryUI": true,
             "bAutoWidth": true,
             "bFilter": false,
             "bSort": false,
             "bInfo": false,
             "bPaginate": false,
             "bDestroy": false,
             "aoColumnDefs": [
                { "sType": "html", "aTargets": [ 0,1,3 ] },
                {"sWidth": "350px", "aTargets": [ 4 ] },//,
                {"sWidth": "100px", "aTargets": [ 3 ] },//,
                {"sWidth": "165px", "aTargets": [ 2 ] },//,
                {"sWidth": "165px", "aTargets": [ 1 ] },//,
                {"sWidth": "165px", "aTargets": [ 0 ] }//,
                //{"sWidth": "15%", "aTargets": [ 3 ] },
                //{"sWidth": "15%", "aTargets": [ 2 ] },
                //{"sWidth": "15%", "aTargets": [ 1 ] },
                //{"sWidth": "15%", "aTargets": [ 0 ] },
             ],
             "oLanguage": {
                "sEmptyTable": "No data available"
             },
             "bRetrieve": true,
             "fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
                 //$( ".documents").ckeditor(planningeditorConfig);
                 alert('table redrawn..');
             }
        };
    var oTable =    $(".datatable").dataTable(config);
```

function to add row to the existing table -

```
    $("#add-planning-row").click( function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var aiNew = oTable.fnAddData( [ "", "", "", "", ""] );
        var nRow = oTable.fnGetNodes( aiNew[0] );
        nRow.className = " planningRow "+nRow.className;
        var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nRow);
        var jqTds = $(">td", nRow);
        var loopIndexValue = parseInt($("#loopIndexValue").val());

        var html  = "<input type=\"text\" value=\""+aData[0]+"\"   name=\"projectPlanning["+loopIndexValue+"].eftName\"   class=\"planningField\"  >"
        + "<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"${project.id}\" name=\"projectPlanning["+loopIndexValue+"].projectId\"  class=\"planningField\"  />"
        + "<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"added through ui\" name=\"projectPlanning["+loopIndexValue+"].description\"  class=\"planningField\"  />"
        + "<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"plan for ${project.name}\" name=\"projectPlanning["+loopIndexValue+"].name\"  class=\"planningField\"  />";


        var comboHtml = " <select class=\"combobox\" name=\"projectPlanning["+loopIndexValue+"].itemStatus.id\" id=\"projectPlanning"+loopIndexValue+".itemStatus.id\"  class=\"planningField\"  >  "+
        "   <option value=\"1\">New</option>  "+
        "   <option value=\"2\">On Track</option>  "+
        "   <option value=\"3\">Minor Impact</option>  "+
        "   <option value=\"4\">Major Impact</option>  "+
        "   <option value=\"5\">Complete</option>  "+
        " </select>  ";

        jqTds[0].innerHTML = html;
        jqTds[1].innerHTML = "<input type=\"text\" value=\""+aData[1]+"\"    name=\"projectPlanning["+loopIndexValue+"].item\"  class=\"planningField\"   >";
        jqTds[2].innerHTML = "<input type=\"text\" value=\""+aData[2]+"\"    name=\"projectPlanning["+loopIndexValue+"].itemDate\" class=\"datepicker planningField \"  >";
        jqTds[3].innerHTML = comboHtml;

        jqTds[4].innerHTML = "<textarea type=\"text\" value=\"\"    name=\"projectPlanning["+loopIndexValue+"].document\" class=\"documents  planningField \"  >"+aData[4]+"</textarea>";

        $("#loopIndexValue").val(loopIndexValue+1);
        $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
        $( ".combobox" ).combobox();
        $( ".documents").ckeditor(planningeditorConfig);


        nEditing = nRow;
    } );
```

HTML table -

```
    <div id="planning-tab" class="planning-content">
        <div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
                <input  id="delete-planning-row"  type="button" class="button" value="Delete planning item" />
                <input  id="add-planning-row"  type="button" class="button" value="Add planning item" />
            </div>
        <table id="planning-list" class="datatable" style="width: 1024px;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td> EFT </td>
                    <td> Item </td>
                    <td> Date </td>
                    <td> Status </td>
                    <td> Document </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <c:set value="0" var="loopIndexValue" ></c:set>
            <c:forEach items="${project.projectPlanning}" var="planning" varStatus="status">
                <tr class="planningRow">
                    <td>
                        <input value="<ctg:capitalize text="${planning.eftName}" />" name="projectPlanning[${status.index}].eftName"  class="planningField planningEftName"/>
                        <input type="hidden" value="${planning.id}" name="projectPlanning[${status.index}].id" class="planningField" />
                        <input type="hidden" value="${planning.name}" name="projectPlanning[${status.index}].name" class="planningField" />
                        <input type="hidden" value="${planning.description}" name="projectPlanning[${status.index}].description" class="planningField" />
                        <input type="hidden" value="${project.id}" name="projectPlanning[${status.index}].projectId" class="planningField" />
                        <%-- <input type="hidden" value="${planning.document}" name="projectPlanning[${status.index}].document" class="planningField" /> --%>

                    </td>                   
                    <td>
                        <input value="${planning.item}" name="projectPlanning[${status.index}].item" class="planningField planningItem" />
                    </td>                   
                    <td>
                    <input value="<fmt:formatDate pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" value="${planning.itemDate}" />" name="projectPlanning[${status.index}].itemDate" class="datepicker planningField"/>

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form:select path="projectPlanning[${status.index}].itemStatus.id" items="${projectStatuses}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="id"  cssClass="combobox planningField" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <%-- <form:textarea class="ckeditor" id="ckeditorPlan" name="projectPlanning[${status.index}].document" path="document" rows="1" cols="20" /> --%>
                        <%-- <textarea  class="ckeditor" id="ckeditorPlan" name="projectPlanning[${status.index}].document" rows="1" cols="20" >${planning.document}</textarea> --%>
                        <textarea  contenteditable="true"  name="projectPlanning[${status.index}].document" rows="1" cols="20" class="documents planningField planningDocument">${planning.document}</textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>


            </c:forEach>




            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well.. I tried to resolve this on my own. This seem to be simple, but hard to guess after going through forums and all that cr*p. Ok.. The solution is to reset or destroy your existing ckeditor instances and recreate it. Below is the code snippet -

JQUERY methods -

```
function resetCkEditors(){

    //alert("reseting editors.");

    for(var i in CKEDITOR.instances) {
        /* editor = CKEDITOR.instances[i]
        editor.destroy();
        editor = null; */

        var editorNm = CKEDITOR.instances[i].name;
        editor = CKEDITOR.instances[i];

        if(editorNm.indexOf('projectPlanText') != -1)
        {
            editor.destroy();
            editor = null;
        }

    }
}


    $("#add-planning-row").click( function (e) {

        resetCkEditors(); // -- THIS IS IMPORTANT AND MAKE SURE YOU ARE NOT DESTROYING ALL THE CKEDITOR INSTANCES OTHER THAN THE ONE IN THE DATATABLE

        e.preventDefault();
        var aiNew = oTable.fnAddData( [ "", "", "", "", ""] );
        var nRow = oTable.fnGetNodes( aiNew[0] );
        nRow.className = " planningRow "+nRow.className;
        var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nRow);
        var jqTds = $(">td", nRow);
        var loopIndexValue = parseInt($("#loopIndexValue").val());


        var html  = "<input type=\"text\" value=\""+aData[0]+"\"   name=\"projectPlanning["+loopIndexValue+"].eftName\"   class=\"planningField\"  >"
        + "<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"${project.id}\" name=\"projectPlanning["+loopIndexValue+"].projectId\"  class=\"planningField\"  />"
        + "<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"added through ui\" name=\"projectPlanning["+loopIndexValue+"].description\"  class=\"planningField\"  />"
        + "<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"plan for ${project.name}\" name=\"projectPlanning["+loopIndexValue+"].name\"  class=\"planningField\"  />";

        var comboHtml = " <select class=\"combobox\" name=\"projectPlanning["+loopIndexValue+"].itemStatus.id\" id=\"projectPlanning"+loopIndexValue+".itemStatus.id\"  class=\"planningField\"  >  "+
        "   <option value=\"1\">New</option>  "+
        "   <option value=\"2\">On Track</option>  "+
        "   <option value=\"3\">Minor Impact</option>  "+
        "   <option value=\"4\">Major Impact</option>  "+
        "   <option value=\"5\">Complete</option>  "+
        " </select>  ";



        jqTds[0].innerHTML = html;
        jqTds[1].innerHTML = "<input type=\"text\" value=\""+aData[1]+"\"    name=\"projectPlanning["+loopIndexValue+"].item\"  class=\"planningField\"   >";
        jqTds[2].innerHTML = "<input type=\"text\" value=\""+aData[2]+"\"    name=\"projectPlanning["+loopIndexValue+"].itemDate\" class=\"datepicker planningField \"  >";
        jqTds[3].innerHTML = comboHtml;
        jqTds[4].innerHTML = "<textarea id=\"projectPlanText-["+loopIndexValue+"]\" type=\"text\" value=\"\"    name=\"projectPlanning["+loopIndexValue+"].document\" class=\"documents planningField planningDocument\" >"+aData[4]+"</textarea>";


        $("#loopIndexValue").val(loopIndexValue+1);
        $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
        $( ".combobox" ).combobox();
        $( ".documents").ckeditor(planningeditorConfig); // -- THIS LINE IS IMPORTANT TO SET THE TEXTAREA TO CKEDITOR INSTANCES WITHOUT WHICH ONLY THE NEW ROW WILL HAVE THE CKEDITOR INSTANCE AND REST WILL BE TURNED BACK TO TEXTAREA


        nEditing = nRow;
    } );
```